# CSV file generated from Java adds unwanted question mark (?)

Tags: java, csv, java-io, bufferedwriter, stringbuffer

I am creating a CSV file from Java code. ***(I also generated `HTML` and `txt` files with the same. The problem remains the same.)***

The code is as below.

```
private String writeToFile(StringBuffer csvData, long randomDigits, String type) {
    String fileName = "";
    String filePath = "";
    if ("CSV".equals(type)) {
        filePath = WebConstants.PATH + randomDigits + "CSV.csv";
        fileName = randomDigits + "CSV.csv";
    }
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        bw.write(csvData.toString());
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Now, when the file is generated, all data looks correct.
But at the end of file, there is a question mark (?) which is unwanted.
I debugged the code, when the `bw.write(csvData.toString())` is called, the value of `csvData` does not contain the question mark at the end.

This is how I am creating the `StringBuffer csvData`

```
private StringBuffer saveAsCVSFile(Vector<XYZVO> list) {

    StringBuffer csvData = new StringBuffer();
    XYZVO VO = null;
    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            VO = list.get(i);
            csvData.append(VO.getABC()+",");
            csvData.append(VO.getDEF()+",");
            csvData.append(VO.getGHI()+",");
            csvData.append(VO.getJKL()+",");
            csvData.append(VO.getMNO()+"\n");
        }
    }
    return csvData;
}
```

Here, `XYZVO` contains all `String` or `int` variables.

I also added a code to read the generated file it is as below.

```
private void checkFileData(String filePath) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Line X: "+line);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I check the output of this read code in console, it simply doesn't show the question mark at the end.

If some one has any idea, please inform.

Comment: I think it is present in the `StringBUffer`. How are you putting the data into it?

Comment: I am appending data from my `Vector<String>` with a `for` loop. But I checked the value of `StringBuffer` with a debug at the time of execution of `bw.write(csvData.toString())` line. I found no question mark at the end. The last character I found was newline character. Which I had added last.

Comment: Can you post the full code of how you get them in `Vector<String>` and then how you put it in `StringBuffer`? It has the dependencies all over the way with data

Comment: It's probably not a question mark; it's probably a character that your  console can't render. Check its binary value.

Comment: @Octopus: I have edited the question. Find the code in the same.

Comment: @Bohemian: As I mentioned before, I debugged the execution of code, at the time of writing data to file, the `csvData` variable does not contain any extra character. The last thing I saw was newline and no character after that. And presence of newline you can justify with the code block I just added to my question.

Comment: In the condition of while loop, `(line = br.readLine()) != null` the line is assigned with the next line in the given file. This brings all the data except the question mark. Which I just see when I open the file in Open Office.

Comment: Are you compiling and running the code on the same machine?  Some Windows viewers might show LF as a question mark, so if the file is generated on a unix box, then viewed on a Windows box, a question mark might be shown.  Have you run the test with more than one XYZVO in the Vector?  Is there a question mark between the output XYZVOs?

Comment: I am running the code on Windows machine. And compiling on the same. Plus, `XYZVO` values does not have any question mark in the values. I am trying this with `Vector<XYZVO>` of size 6. The question mark is just added at the end of CSV file, nowhere else.

Comment: @KeyurGolani can you post the output of your getters of Object XYZVO

Comment: That gives the data which is company proprietary. Can't post it here. But those are nothing but `String` and `int` data. In `String` some are Names and some are strictly alphanumeric codes.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the writer, it would be flushed first. So the flush before the close is not necessary. Try removing that.

Comment: Tried removing that. No difference.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the code line- csvData.append(VO.getMNO()+"\n"); causes the issue because at the end of the string buffer you have one unnecessary newline. Just check this out.

Comment: I tried several things regarding this newline. I tried to remove the final newline character but it just shifts the question mark on the last line of data. When the newline character is present, the question mark appears in the next row.

Comment: It might sound weird but try without flushing and closing the buffer writer.

Comment: Well, that gave interesting result. I removed both `bw.flush()` and `bw.close()` and it generated file with only a question mark and no other data. I also tried removing only `bw.close()` but that generated file with all data and question mark.

Comment: Hi @KeyurGolani, any luck on this. I am getting the same issue, and for me, a question mark is getting printed as the first character of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I used FileWriter to achieve the same :

```
try
    {
    FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(csv);
    writer.append("Mobile Number");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("Message");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("Service");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("Time");
    writer.append('\n');


    writer.append(mobileNumber);
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append(message);
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append(service);
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append(time);
    writer.append('\n');

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    //catch Exception here
}
```

### Using your code

I used your code but its working at my end .......

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, UnknownHostException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Test a = new Test();
        Vector<MyObject> testObj =  new Vector<MyObject>();
        testObj.add(new MyObject());
        testObj.add(new MyObject());
        testObj.add(new MyObject());
        a.checkFileData(a.writeToFile(a.saveAsCVSFile(testObj),123456789 , "CSV"));

    }


    private StringBuffer saveAsCVSFile(Vector<MyObject> list) {

        StringBuffer csvData = new StringBuffer();
        MyObject VO = null;
        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                VO = list.get(i);
                csvData.append(VO.getABC()+",");
                csvData.append(VO.getDEF()+",");
                csvData.append(VO.getGHI()+",");
                csvData.append(VO.getJKL()+",");
                csvData.append(VO.getMNO()+"\n");
            }
        }
        return csvData;
    }

    private void checkFileData(String filePath) {
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Line X: "+line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private String writeToFile(StringBuffer csvData, long randomDigits, String type) {
        String fileName = "";
        String filePath = "";
        if ("CSV".equals(type)) {
            filePath = randomDigits + "CSV.csv";
            fileName = randomDigits + "CSV.csv";
        }
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
            bw.write(csvData.toString());
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileName;
    }


class MyObject{
    static int count =1;

    public String getABC() {
        return "ABC"+(++count);
    }

    public String getMNO() {
        return "MNO"+count;
    }

    public String getJKL() {
        return "JKL"+count;
    }

    public String getGHI() {
        return "GHI"+count;
    }

    public String getDEF() {
        return "DEF"+count;
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Line X: ABC2,DEF2,GHI2,JKL2,MNO2
Line X: ABC3,DEF3,GHI3,JKL3,MNO3
Line X: ABC4,DEF4,GHI4,JKL4,MNO4
```

Comment: Please check the question again. The output you mentioned, I am getting the same. The question mark appears only when I open the generated file in Open Office or MS Office.